# Table access for all users and logins

Tags: sql-server

I have a server in which *many users and logins already have access to*

I was wondering if it is possible to allow all of these users and logins `SELECT` privilege to a specific table within a database?

Comment: Do a loop over users and grant select?

Comment: Are those login windows's account ? (in a domain) or SQL Logins ?
If they are in the AD, I guess best practice is to use AD groups for security. If you have an AD group with everyone that required that select permission being member of it, then you only have to grant the select on the AD Group (and not on all logins). Otherwise, I would go with a loop kinda TSQL as suggested by Lennart

Comment: Logins can occur using both windows's accounts (windows authentication) and SQL logins (username/password).

Comment: @thepieman314 please don't forget to vote up and mark as answer, if any of the answers are good for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below command:

```
grant select on [Your_Table] to [public]
```

This grants `SELECT` permission on [Your_Table] to ALL existing and future users inside your database

If you do not want to grant select to Everyone (public) in the database, but rather to limited set of database users - in this case you need to create custom database role, grant select to this role, add users to this role

**Update**: additionally, if you log in to server as a "different user" (login) - make sure your login has a mapped user inside your database in question, and that user has "connect database" permission;

Comment: The question states "which many users and logins already have access to", not all.  Who knows how the database usage may change in the future and having that little gem waiting buried in the security policy might be a great way to a lawsuit.

Comment: This does not seem to work.  I ran the command and it completed successfully.  However, when I logged in under a different user, it says that the database in which the table exists is not accessible.

Comment: @thepieman314 Answer assumes your logins/users already have access to the database. (not only the server but to database too). "Different user" you are using, seems to be login that does not have a user inside a database, so it can connect to the server, but can't connect/use database in question. You would need to run command "use [Your_Database] create user [Your_User] for login [Your_Login]" to grant that "different user" access to the database

Comment: Would there be a way to create this user for all of the users/logins that already exist on the server, as well as any other logins/users that would happen to be added to the server in the future?

Comment: no, you would need to grant connect permission to this database to each login individually -> create a user for login in the database

Comment: OK, thanks for all the info Aleksey.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to create a role, assign that role select access to the table in question, then assign the users and logins to that role.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/database-level-roles?view=sql-server-ver15